# Passing parameters in url by hiding parameters

Tags: angularjs, state

I want to pass parameters in url by hiding parameters in url

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
url: "/home",
templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
params: { hiddenOne: null, }
```

I am passing `hiddenOne` as a parameter from one controller to another. It works but when I refresh that page the `hiddenOne` in state parameters becomes null. I want that value after refreshing also. How to do that ?

Comment: You can use local storage to store the value and update it when the `hiddenOne` is passed as parameter.

Comment: it is secure data so i should not use localstorage so if it have any otherway

Comment: @naguluvemula If it is that secure , then encrypt it .

Comment: how to do that could you please provide the example